# is shared hosting secure?

Tags: php, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have a question with security point of view, it might sound silly but i'm very interested to know. If someone uploads his code on shared hosting (assuming some general US based web hosting companies where it cost about $5 to 10$ a month), is it secure there? Would the other users hosted on same servers somehow access the code? (and of course the hosting administrators can access?) In that case is it really safe to host on shared hosting companies?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Questions about security should be asked in [security.se].  In the future, please ask questions like this in one of those two more appropriate places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how the individual web hosting company have setup there systems.

You need to trust the company you are hosting with but any half decent hosting company should have it locked down so customers can't access each others code. It is always a risk that someone with access to the same server could find it easier to access your data but again this shouldn't be a massive issue with a trusted well known provider.

The best bet is to read company reviews and see what existing customer think about them.

Answer (score 2):

If the company has properly configured the server, no -- other users on the same server will not be able to see your code. However, the administrator will be able to, and may state this in the contract agreement.

Review the contract when purchasing shared hosting to see what rights the administrator claims. Usually, they'll only access your data when there is a problem, such as any indication you are running a script that violates your contract agreement.

Additionally, regardless of the contract agreement, an administrator will likely be required to provide access to law enforcement if they have a warrant, based on the laws local to the country where you are hosting. They may or may not be allowed to notify you, again, based on local laws.

If you're concerned about intellectual property, just make sure you're using a reputable company for hosting. Chances are, stealing your code isn't worth the risk.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the hosting administrator has obviously access to your code, but of course they should have some policy that prevent for usage of your data.
Other user could not "generally speaking" see your code, but this strongly depends on server configuration. For example, if some other webmaster host a web application in the same server and this is exploited, it is possible that also your application is affected.
Moreover, it could be easyer for other user using the same server to access your data instead of a "normal" attack to a private server.

btw, you should be a good sysadmin to protect a server better than a pros that does this thing all day long, so, it basically depends on your system admininstration knowledge.

As you posted this question, you're probably not that good in this kind of stuff, so you may think as a shared hosting like something acceptably secure. (of course, it also depends on what do you want to host)

Answer (score 0):

More professional shared hosting providers use a **`mod_suphp`/`suexec`** setup. That provides a pretty reliable demarcation between users. And going from there you can often work reliably without conflicts from other users.

Of course you still have to live with the performance impacts of a shared server. And an exploit in the system libraries can be taken advantage from any of the other accounts still.

Comment: plenty of professional shared hosting companies out there that use mod_php as well. there are reliable ways to overcome mod_php limitations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any fully secure web hosting, even if it is a dedicated server.But in most cases, dedicated servers are much more secure than share hosting. With dedicated server, you own a physical server while going with shared hosting, you share a server with others and there are so many factors you cannot control,such as neighbors.

Let's come back to shared hosting security. Though there is no any fully secure shared hosting, you can find a more secure one. The security largely depends on what your web host do with security while you can leverage it too. If your web host has poor secure configurations, it is more possible for hackers and even neighbors to access your account and data.

What you need to do is to go for a shared hosting with higher secure configuration, like advanced firewall, if you can only afford a shared hosting. Here you can check out http://tutorials.hostucan.net/what-to-consider-when-pick-up-a-secure-hosting to see how to select a secure hosting.

Answer (score 0):

If they use Cloud linux instead of Centos 
CSF production tools , SSL , other security plugins and configurations the shared hosting is secured ,
If you purchase dedicated server or vps you have to purchase all the licence , security  plugins for the same configuration its very expensive

My Recommendation If its shared or [dedicated server](https://villagehosting.in/hosting/dedicated-server) **use cloudlinux and install paid csf plugins and add human verification robots in your site make your site secure , avoid free plugins and theme in your site or theme**

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting means a single server is shared between multiple users. So, when it comes to security it depends on the hosting providers as there are some techniques through which they isolate the environment of an individual user. But still, all users have the same server IP that somehow put them in danger and security breach.

I always prefer a dedicated or separate setup for my websites and I used Cloudways. I have a dedicated server IP and my server resources aren't shared between multiple users. I'm feeling pretty secure with CW.