# Any PHP framework to use SECURELY on shared hosting?

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, cakephp, symfony1

Are there PHP frameworks that would allow me to generate an application and then use it SECURELY on a shared hosting, as far as a shared hosting security can be achieved? By this I mean, for example, not requiring any app/tmp directory with 777 access.

Not Symfony -> http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SharedHostingNotSecure

Not CakePHP -> http://book.cakephp.org/view/911/Permissions

CodeIgniter -> "If you're a developer who lives in the real world of shared hosting accounts and clients with deadlines..." - looks promising, maybe this one? But I couldn't find anything specific to shared hosting file permissions in the documentation

Maybe ZendFramework? (I am not sure if it is the same category as PHP framework, looks like)

Any existing possible frameworks to use SECURELY on shared hosting??

Comment: *(sidenote)* just because a framework doesnt use 777 for folder permissions doesnt mean it is secure. it still largely depends on your own awareness of possible security related issues whether the application you build with it will be secure or not.

Comment: That's also only a problem for low-end shared hosting. Contemporary setups use suexec/suphp, and don't need any world-write permissions.

Comment: Give a try to [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/)

Comment: I think you need to revise your definition of "secure". You are looking for a framework that isn't concerned by file permissions.

Comment: I have more or less the same security concern as the person here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384554/is-shared-hosting-secure   -- and it looks like it is possible to have a secure shared host

Comment: eee any frame work is as secure on shared hosting its up to server configuration and not in php
and if the manual specyfys you to do a 777 just make it 770 or 700 as you probebly own the file yourself

Comment: I think Symfony is now out of scope for this issue because it won't take advantage of the suPHP even in version 1.4 without some manual patching, no official patch, as described here: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/4412 - I take a look at CakePHP next.

Comment: After testing, I'd like to accept @mario answer (above) about suPHP, but it's a comment. If mario reads it please create an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having to declare directories with `777` permissions is only a problem on cheapo and entry-level shared hosting systems. It's common to see the safe_mode hack and openbasedir restrictions in that area, which only prevent access via PHP but not other CGI interpreters.

Contemporary server setups use **suexec/suphp**, where every PHP scripts runs under the current accounts permissions. Therefore you don't need any world-write directories and most PHP application should be secure against cross-account tampering at least. The framework itself doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the right problem from the wrong point of view.

Having a directory with the rights 777 is not unsecure per se.

Having a 777'ed directory on a shared hosting is unsecure, **because** the http daemon is run for all clients under the same system account.

It is an intrinsic "feature" of *shared hosting*, that's why it's the cheapest. Yep, it's not cheap for nothing, it's cheap at the price of security.

If security is that important to you, buy a VPS. Nowadays VPSes are cheap enough.

Comment: I know VPS are secure. But in my situation, I am looking for optimal solution for shared hosting.

Comment: Then it really doesn't matter - your application lives in an unsecure environment and will remain unsecure no matter what you do.

Comment: But assuming that the server admin is a trusted person. Only other users are untrusted. Then I think I can consider shared hosting secure, if I don't do something unsecure myself like make 777 directory. 777 allows other users to write to MY directory and is unsecure indeed.

Comment: That's not how security works. You cannot just take pieces of stuff you consider secure and leave out anything else. That's why they're called "attack vectors", because they "add up" like in maths: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction Your weak link is the fact that different users which you don't trust run their apps under the same system account as you do - so they can do everything you can do too. That's the definition of *shared hosting* and in order to counteract that, you need to change the hosting model, from *shared* to *private*.

Comment: I know I am saying things you don't want to hear. What I'm saying is the pure technical truth.

Comment: You are right in general. But the level of security of a renomed shared hosting server is acceptable for me. There is some risk, but it's cheaper and I accept the risk as other people do, and as my client does. The only purpose of my original question is that I don't want to decrease the level of security even more by adding something which is obviously unsecure, as would be creating a mode 777 directory. But I am currently investigating the suphp thing.

Comment: You are not decreasing the level of security, nor are you increasing it. It's just the same low level of security and maybe a false sense of security which may make you feel more secure and you'll sleep better at night, BUT it's not more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com). Doesn't require any file permissions as far as I know. Just needs some proper configuration. And yes, it is a PHP Framework. My entire library is under root owner, with read permissions for everyone and it works fine. Never needed to chmod anything. When it comes to libraries you can always define your own tmp path if it's needed by the class.

Comment: How is ZF secure on shared hosting?  Please explain your suggestion. Throwing in the name of your favorite framework is not useful.

Comment: Well, from what I understood from the OP's definition of "secure", I think he meant file permission wise.

Answer (score 0):

Most successful attacks happen because the user/admin sticks with the defaults; which are well-known. See Windows attacks. It's unbelievable how many "administrators" keep not only default URLs, default directory structures but also User IDs and passwords. On my website I see repeatedly some log in attempts at /wp-login.php with ID:PW as admin:admin. I don't even know if these are some defaults and my website is not even WP but it seems to be and I think those hackers will get lucky every once in a while.

Security I believe is always about raising the bar, make it more difficult. There is never a 100% guarantee of security. I think you can choose whatever framework or application but it is your job to make it more difficult by changing the defaults.

I can only speak for ZF and you can do some freaky configuration nobody will ever guess; unless your application has occasional errors and you show your error messages with full information.

Comment: Nice! Of all the answers mine gets a down vote? Please shed some light why exactly mine.

Comment: Maybe because what you are suggesting sound like **security through obscurity"*.

Comment: @tereško I guess. However, the question here is about security on shared hosting and my answer is in response to that particular question. For that obscurity is one of the first defenses you have to take.