# Can you see PHP scripts client side?

Tags: php, security, ssl

I'm only asking this to make my site as secure as possible since it will be dealing with personal information.  This is why I chose PHP to code with as it is ran all server side but I heard there are certain tricks out there that you can read scripts if the URL is learned where the script is.  I haven't seen this personally my self so I'm just wanting some clarification to make sure that coding in PHP is this best choice security wise.

Basically I want to have at least of a likely to be hacked in some way as possible.  I will be applying SSL certificates once I'm done with the development of the site and I know that'll help quite a bit with information being transmitted back and forth being encrypted.

Comment: Only if you've misconfigured your servers

Comment: Just because a user can't see the source code doesn't mean it isn't exploitable.  Look up SQL injection and cross-site scripting.  The only provably secure site is the trivial empty page (assuming the server is configured correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody can see your code because Apache (or whatever web server you use) is instructed to EXECUTE any .php files rather than simply serve (display) them as it does by default (with .html, .css, .js, etc).

I think what you may have heard of is a general security concern using PHP in general - If you are using a shared host (where other users also use the same server as you) they will generally be able to view your code programmatically, that is to say they can write a PHP script which lists your PHP scripts -- this does require that they know the physical directory your scripts are stored in, but again they could write a PHP script to try and discover this.

Generally speaking this isn't an issue, but if I'm doing anything of a sensitive nature (such as taking card payments) I always ensure I'm working in an environment only I have programmatical access to (ie. a virtual server or a dedicated server -- By virtual server I mean a virtual machine to which I have dedicated exclusive access, do not confuse this with "Virtual Hosts" which are shared servers).

Comment: If your shared host allows access to other users files I would switch the hoster.

Comment: Without giving a tutorial on hacking other users' accounts all I will say is consider that Apache is running FOR ALL USERS as a single system user such as wwwrun or apache - that means that if apache can access it so can anyone who can tell apache what to do, ie users with accounts on the shared host. Even if you are on a shared host which has some mechanism to get around this, it's bad practice to assume nobody is ever going to hack you and look at your source -- code security as deep as you can!

Comment: Correct, yes you can -- the hardest part for a would-be attacker is ensuring they're on the same server as you - generally their directory is easy to work out by using the context of your own - that is to say if I get a path for mine as /srv/www/my.site.address/ theirs will be /srv/www/their.site.address. Some hosts obfuscate this info but if it comes to it you could use brute force to find their directory if you really wanted to.

Comment: interesting my hoster has a own session folder for each user. In your answered it sounds like its normal for shared hosting to be insecure. I agree that there is a higher risk. But it should not be normal to access other users sessions or files. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6384579

Comment: @RolandStarke While it's great that your host has taken measures to increase security, please accept that not all hosts are equal and it's often difficult (without actually trying to hack someone else's account which is illegal at least here in the UK) to ascertain how the host has set their systems up as mentioned in your link. Code for worst case scenario, never assume your host can protect you, never take their word for it that they do. Paranoia is extremely valuable when it comes to site security!

Answer (score 2):

No one can read your code unless you have error reporting enabled and an error occurs that exposes the code. Make sure you have error logging on and error reporting off when you are ready for users.

Set ini_set('display_errors', 'Off'); in your php code (or directly into your ini if possible)