# About Username and password security

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am making a custom storage page,to store information.

```
<form  action="files/form.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <input name="submit" value="Send" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

So here is the form I have it set to a premade user and password that are saved in MySQL database.When the form is sent it goes to

**form.php** file which contains the form that the user will input his information

```
<?php 
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
?>
<?php if ($user == "Admin" && $pass == "12345"){ ?>
    form.php content goes in here
<?php }else{ ?>
    <span>Wrong password</span>
<?php } ?>
```

So the main question here is,is this actually safe? or I should look up a better way to do this

The way i plan to keep a user logged in is to keep the **$user** and **$password** in a **$_SESSION** untill the user visits **logout.php** which will clear the **SESSION**

My code actually works ,its fine.

I just want to know if this is safe?
Note:**User** and **Password** are placeholder for the moment it wont be 12345

Comment: You're storing username & password in the database but the login is validated against hardcoded values in the if-statement ? Don't understand the setup.

Comment: You should only store hashed and saltet passwords for that take a look at phps password_verify function and  you should use HTTPS.

Comment: @JazzCat its just a placeholder,before i do it

Comment: @Innervisions then i'd suggest you post the entire code with the format the password is saved in (in the database) and your sql-query.

Comment: There is no need to store the password in the session storing the user is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that if anyone were to gain access to your source code (which is a major risk if you are sharing your host with other users/sites) can see what the password is.

The recommended way to store a password is to use a one-way hash - that is to say only the encrypted version of the password is ever stored. This would usually have the password stored in the database in its encrypted form, and you would then encrypt (using the same method) the user's input and check the encrypted form against the one in the database.

I won't expand your answer to use a database, but here it is statically set which should at least help explain what I mean:

```
<?php 
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
?>
<?php if ($user == "Admin" && sha1($pass) == "8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964"){ ?>
    //form.php content goes in here
<?php }else{ ?>
    <span>Wrong password</span>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that I have used sha1 encryption here, there are [plenty of others to choose from](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) other than this too. Also note that `8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964` is the hash as returned by `sha1("12345")`.

***Additional:***

As mentioned in a comment, sha1 is no longer recommended and I use it here for simplicity of syntax; in a production environment consider using [password_hash with bcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If they get access to the source code you've got bigger issues already.

Comment: what about sql injection

Comment: There's no SQL in the answer either -- as I said I am simply explaining the method of using one-way hashes, not giving a tutorial on using SQL.

Comment: @ceejayoz Anyone on a shared server can see your code if they are so inclined, as per my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023105/can-you-see-php-scripts-client-side/34023434#34023434).

Comment: You shouldn't use SHA1 for password hashing anymore. SHA1 collisions isn't just in theory nowadays. I'd suggest you'd use password_hash with BCRYPT

Comment: @SteJ If you're on shared hosting that does that you've got *other* bigger issues already.

Comment: @SteJ then I'd strongly suggest changing host - shared servers can run per-user isolated apache/php setups perfectly fine.

Comment: @JimL they *can* but in practice they're usually not. I steer clear of vhosts for this very reason. I'd also say that even if you think nobody can access your source, it's still a good idea to make sure that if somebody DOES gain access to it you're not going to compromise security.